# Delete template link in a .Doc

Tags: c#, templates, ms-word

I'm using a C# application which create .doc files from a template.
The problem is that I don't keep the templates and, when the template file doesn't exist anymore, the .doc file makes a very long time to open.
I've understood that Word try to find the template file before opening the doc file. It seems useless cause when Word opens the document (after a long time) it shows perfectly.

This is the code I use to open the file :

```
 wordApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
 wordApplication.Documents.Add("PATH TO DOC");
```

There is no problem if the template file exists but it takes a very long time if it do not.

Any idea on how to remove that "link" between the template and the doc created from the template ? (In C#)

Comment: It might actually be easier to convert the `dotx` template to `docx` and use that. `Documents.Add` still works. I have implemented a small export VBA using this idea here: https://github.com/coezbek/office-automation-excel2word-document-properties/blob/main/Excel2Word.bas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set_AttachedTemplate` of the `Word.Document` object to change the template.
You might have to call `UpdateStyles` on the document to copy over the style information from the new template.

Comment: Oh it seems to be perfect but I wonder if there is a rule to set the default template ?  
I've seen that it would be Normal.odt but how can I make the AttachedTemplate to be Normal.odt without knowing the full path ? (the code must be portative)